# Find point on a line using its orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

How to find a point $\bf{X}$ on a line from its orthogonal projection $\bf{P}$ on another line.

Lets say we have vectors $\bf{A}$, $\bf{P}$ which start at $\textbf{0}$, how to find point $\bf{X}$?
[image]

I know that orthogonal projection is:

$${\bf P} = \frac{\bf{X} \dot{} \bf{B}}{\bf B \dot{} B} {\bf B}$$ ${\bf B}$ - vector on blue line starting at $\bf{0}$. But how to get $\bf{X}$, when you have $\bf{P}$?

Comment: Visibly, $X=\lambda A$. Express the ortogonality of $P$ and $PX=X-P$.

Comment: So I get that $(P - \lambda A)\dot{} P = 0$. From dot product definition: $$p_1^2 - \lambda a_1 p_1 + p_2^2 - \lambda a_2 p_2 = 0\\
\lambda = \frac{p_1^2 + p_2^2}{a_1p_1 + a_2p_2}$$Is it correct?

Comment: Yep, $\lambda=P^2/(A\cdot P)$, $X=(P^2/(A\cdot P))A$.

Comment: Thank you, Yves Daoust. You have solved my problem. Put it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visibly, $X=\lambda A$. Expressing orthogonality
$$(\lambda A-P)\cdot P=0,$$
hence
$$X=\frac{P^2}{A\cdot P}A.$$